# Vim Syntax Highlighting Question

Tags: vim

I have a doubt about vim,

I installed the editor on my ubuntu 13.10 and everything is ok.

but when I create a file ".txt, or .conf" the highlighting isn't  enabled, I put "#" and " but not change color in the file

But when I open a file ".conf" the highlighting is enabled.

the syntax is ON

someone can help me ?

Comment: `.txt` is a plaintext file.  And so is a `.conf`.  What makes you think that there's supposed to be highlighting on those?

Comment: because when I open a .conf it open highlighting

Comment: There is no one `.conf` syntax, because it differs by program a lot of times.  If you open in GEdit, or anything else which has syntax highlighting, unless there's a line at the beginning saying `#!/bin/something` or something which defines the syntax language, they usually don't highlight on `.conf` files.  I just tested by doing `vim znc.conf` on my ZNC config file, and `vim nginx.conf` on my nginx conf file and there's 0 syntax highlighting, maybe you have a line at the beginning of the specific conf files that dictates the language/syntax to highlight with?

Comment: My doubt is because when I open a file. conf it is on highlighting, and when I create a txt file. conf or. highlighting it does not get in

Answer (score 11):

The file ending `.conf` has no syntax set by default.  Different configuration files have different syntax, so vim cannot use the same syntax for all `.conf` files.  To handle this, vim looks at the whole file name and compares it to the patterns found in `filetype.vim` (located at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim` on my system)

For example, say you opened the file `apache.conf`, vim will look in `filetype.vim` until it finds something like:

```
       au BufNewFile,BufRead apache.conf*,apache2.conf* setfiletype apache
```

which tells vim to use the `apache` syntax highlighting file for any file that begins in `apache.conf`. Try creating a new file called `apache.conf` and you should get apache syntax highlighting for that file.

Another way vim can set the syntax for a file is with modelines. Modelines let you run vim commands for specific files. They can be found at the top or bottom of files and look something like this:

```
# vim: syntax=apache
```

For more info on modelines checkout `:help modeline` in vim.

Answer (score 6):

[juxiliary's answer](/a/439723) is correct. I found that the easiest way to set this when you know you want this style is an abbreviated version of his answer:

```
:setf apache
```

You may want to mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I think your question is "If I save a file, will it later have highlighting on".  Until you save the file, unless you've added a line at the beginning of the file (such as `#!/bin/bash`), it won't have any highlighting.  Highlighting is defined by the first line of the file, or by the file extension.

If there's special `.conf` highlighting, based on the filename pattern, it will show up when you next open the `.conf` file.

All `.txt` files are plain-text and don't have any syntax highlighting unless the file opens with `#!/bin/bash` or some other similar line.

---

TL;DR; the syntax highlighting is not saved with the file.  It's determined internally with Vim, when the file is opened.  (Or, if it's a new file, at first save)